# Identifying isolated elements in homogeneous groups

Tags: python, list, nlp, grouping

I am working on a task of text segmentation in Python.
The texts I am working on should be segmented into 4 sections (based on what they're talking about), let's call them A, B, C and D, usually in this order. These texts are divided in relatively short text segments. The sections are unique (only one per text) and homogeneous (never split, which kinda repeats previous point).

I have got a neural network that identifies the section a segment belongs to with 90% precision, which I'm happy about.
However, when it comes to the last 10%, they are often an isolated segments erroneously tagged, surrounded by other elements righteously tagged.

I can visualise this trough a list of tuples looking like this:

`[(segment1, A), (segment2, A), (segment3, B), (segment4, A), (segment5, A), (segment6, C), (segment6, C)]`

In this case, segment3 should be tagged as A, not B, because the sections in the document are always homogeneous. How can I identify a homogeneous group and therefore correct isolated items?

My current method consists in saying "if the element before and the element after are tagged the same, but not the element in the middle, correct the element in the middle" but I'm convinced there's a better way to do this (maybe using a different way of formatting my data?).

However, what am I to do in the case where there are 2 isolated itams next to one another?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If it is safe to assume that single outliers are always surrounded by two correctly labeled neighbors, one could try to use triplets like these (neglecting the first and last elements, which would be just pre-/appended):

```
def sort_by_label(items):
    return sorted(items, key=lambda x: x[1])

[(unsorted[1][0], sort_by_label(unsorted)[1][1]) for unsorted in zip(segments, segments[1:], segments[2:])]
```

with segments being your result list of tuples.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer :) It looks a lot like what I'm currently trying. Truly, if isolated elements come only alone, then triplets should probably do.

However (and I just edited my post to specify it), how should I deal with possible groups of 2 contiguous isolated/mistagged elements?

I don't know if it's doable and wouldn't cause more harm than it would solve.
Thanks for helping anyway :)

Comment: If there is no way to distinguish 2 mistagged elements from a small 2-element segment labeled correctly, then the heuristics might cause more harm than good.

Comment: That is probably the definite answer to my problem, since I can have sections of 2 elements only.

Thanks for your help!